# Как сделать чтоб при установке программы в реестр заносилась запись с путём к программе

Tags: delphi, реестр, inno-setup

Я использую программу Inno Setup, мне надо чтоб при установке моей программы в реест заносилась запись, с путём к папке которую при установке выбрал пользователь. А лучше вообще без путя, чтоб в реесте появилась запись, наверное с id, ну просто вдруг пользователь установит программу, а потом её куда нибуть перенесёт. Короче я в этом новичок, не очень понимаю, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: хотите сказать InnoSetup не умеет создавать ветки/ключи в реестре что ли? И нужно ли создавать это при установке? если вам путь один черт не нужен никакой. Создавайте/проверяйте при старте программы, `TRegistry` вам в помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как производится сохранение пути в реестр (пример, путь указываете свой):

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\My Program\Settings"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "InstallPath"; ValueData: "{app}"
```

`Root` - корневой элемент

`Subkey` - путь к ветке реестра (указываете свой)

`ValueType` - тип переменной

`ValueName` - имя переменной

`ValueData` - значение (в данном случае {app} - это путь выбранный пользователем, если надо указать свое значение, то фигурные скобки не нужны)

Более детально все это описано в справке к Inno Setup
http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_registrysection.htm